# It was not possible to connect to the redis server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I am trying to compose my project, but got this error:

> It was not possible to connect to the Redis server(s). UnableToConnect
> on localhost:6379/Interactive

How can I fix or find a problem? Thank you.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  catalogdb:
    image: mongo

  cartdb:
    image: redis:alpine

  eshop.catalog.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}eshopcatalogapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: EShop.Catalog.API/Dockerfile

  eshop.cart.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}eshopcartapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: EShop.Cart.API/Dockerfile

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  catalogdb:
    container_name: catalogdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db

  cartdb:
    container_name: cartdb
    restart: always    
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"

  eshop.catalog.api:
    container_name: catalog.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogdb:27017"
    depends_on:
      - catalogdb
    ports:
      - "8000:80"

  eshop.cart.api:
    container_name: cart.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "CacheSettings:ConnectionString=basketdb:6379"
    depends_on:
      - cartdb
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
```

[image]

Comment: Your service is named `cartdb`, but you are trying to connect to `basketdb:6379`.

Comment: @Anton Thank you, I have fixed it , but same problem still exists

Comment: @Anton Fixed. Problem was with connection string.(inconsistency between appsettings and docker-compose.override.yml.